# What was the fate of the Mirror of Erised?

Tags: harry-potter

The Mirror of Erised is a powerful magical object. The last *mention* is in the final Harry Potter book and (I believe) the last time we actually *see* the Mirror is in the first book when Dumbledore tells Harry that he'll be moving it.

**Is anything known of its ultimate fate?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### It was put back into the Room of Requirement (where Dumbledore originally found it), and then destroyed by fiendfyre in book 7.

> Albus Dumbledore, who brings it out of hiding, puts it back where he found it when it has achieved his purpose in Philosopher’s Stone. We must conclude, therefore, that **the mirror was destroyed**, along with all the other contents of the Room of Requirement, during the Battle of Hogwarts.
>
> <sub>Pottermore: Mirror of Erised ([behind paywall](https://usd.shop.pottermore.com/products/hogwarts_an_incomplete_and_unreliable_guide__ebook_english))</sub>

Comment: Interesting. Does it specify whether or not he found it in the Room of Hidden Things? Or just another Room of Requirement? Because Deathly Hallows seemed pretty sure that he didn't know about the former.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - It heavily implies that it was The Room of Hidden Things, seeing as I don't know of a different one that got destroyed in the Battle of Hogwarts. It doesn't mention it by name though.

Comment: So when Harry says that Flitwick and Dumbledore were too smart too ever stumble across the Room of Hidden Things he was wrong... Although I've also always taken his comment in Goblet of Fire about chamberpots as a sign that he didn't know about the RoR at all.

Comment: The paragraph in question is absent from the current Pottermore article.

Comment: @Alex - Which is why I specified in my citation that it's behind a paywall. If you want to see it you'll need to either pay the money or pirate.

Comment: It's in the "Hogwarts: A Complete and Unreliable Guide" ebook as well.

Comment: @TheAsh - Which is where I cited. I see that the link is dead now, but you can still read the url.